# show default value in select box cakephp

Tags: cakephp, timezone, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am new to cakephp .. i am implementing a Timezone feature in my webapp i am using this timezone helper class in order to show time in my select box

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/MarkAlanEvans/2009/12/17/updated-timezone-helper

in my view i am echoing timezone in select box like this

```
  echo $this->Timezone->select('timezone');
```

what i am doing right now is i am taking the value of whatever the time user has selected and then update the field of timezone in database ... what i want now is when the user wants to again change the timezone how  he can see his old timezone in selectbox as a default value .. the first thing i dont know how can i add the default value to my selectbox

my helper class has this function

```
 function select($fieldname, $label="Please Choose a timezone") { 

     $list = $this->Form->input($fieldname, array("type"=>"select", "label"=>$label, "options"=>$this->timezones, "error"=>"Please choose a timezone")); 
    return $this->output($list); 
  }
```

2nd thing is this as if i want to show the default value, obviously i have to query from the database and then retreive the old timezone of the user..  so the problem is if i have to  attach the default value to my helper class for example like this

```
   $list = $this->Form->input($fieldname,  array("type"=>"select",'default'=>'$oldtimezone', "label"=>$label, "options"=>$this->timezones, "error"=>"Please choose a timezone")); 
    return $this->output($list);
```

so in order to do  should i have to loadmodel in helper class and then query in helper class? is that possible ? or is that i am not going against cakephp or mvc rules ? so then my next question becomes how can i load the modal inside helper.

because if i can be able to add default value to here like this

```
  echo $this->Timezone->select('timezone',array('default'=>'oldtimezone'));
```

then i think there is no need for me to make changes in the helper class as i simple pass variable from controller to this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to pass default values to the view is to do that in the else block of the controller:

```
if (posted) {
    //validate and save
} else {
    //default values here
    $this->request->data['Modelname']['timezone'] = $timeZoneFromDb;
}
```

This way you leverage the controllers logic and you dont have to do anything in the view/helper.

See http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/ for details (default value section).

Comment: thankyou mark.. it works great ... thankkkkkkkkk you ,,i dont know that i have to just write a single line code for this